# how to rename a pickedfile from image_picker in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, rename, imagepicker

I want to rename the image name which is a pickedfile type when i'm uploading that image to the server.
when it's uploading image name automatically changes like this scaled_image_picker825656736600296027.jpg

getting image code :-

```
  void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(
      source: source,
      imageQuality: 20,
    );
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile;
    });
  }
```

uploading code is :-

```
void UploadImage() async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(URLs.image));
    request.fields['CompanyCode']=  "${widget.CompanyCode}";
    request.fields['empCode'] ='$user_id';
    request.fields['documentType']="POD";
    if (_imageFile != null && widget.image == null) {
      print('Original path: ${_imageFile.path}');
      String dir = path.dirname(_imageFile.path);
      String newPath = path.join(dir, widget.docketno + '-${DateTime.now()}.jpg');
      print('NewPath: ${newPath}');
       _imageFile.renameSync(newPath); // renameSync is showing error
      request.files
          .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file',_imageFile.path));
    }
    else if(_imageFile ==null && widget.image != null){
      print('AddingUserProfilePic ${widget.image.path}');
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', widget.image.path));
    }
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseBody = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    myData = json.decode(responseBody.body);
    print('Status code is : ${response.statusCode}  && ${response}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      responseResult = myData['filePath'];
      print('the filepath is ' + responseResult.substring(60));
      image_path = responseResult.substring(60);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Uploaded Successfully');
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => delivered(CompanyCode : widget.CompanyCode,docketno :widget.docketno,Year: widget.Year,
          drsno:widget.drsno,challan: widget.challan , package :widget.package , response : image_path)));
      // Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
      //   return count++ == 2;
      // });
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Upload Failed');
    }
  }
```

renameSync is showing the error that The method 'renameSync' isn't defined for the type 'PickedFile'.
so how can i rename my image file????

Answer (score 1):

`PickedFile` is not `File`, it's just a result object of picked file.

You can use it's path to create a `File` and use `File`'s `renameSync`:

```
File(_imageFile.path).renameSync(newPath);
```

Comment: but it still prints the same path

Comment: an error also occurred Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.flutter_app/files/Pictures/scaled_image_picker325856353267804129.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: After the file renamed, you should use the newPath file to do the things you want, becase the old file(_imageFile.path) is not exist any more.

Comment: but the newPath is string and in fromPath only files are uploading

Comment: You have the path already, then just use `File(newPath)` - this is a file.

Comment: Status code is : 500 and the circular progress indicator is continously loading